# Select columns based on != condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I have a dataframe and I have a list of some column names that correspond to the dataframe. How do I filter the dataframe so that it != the list of column names, i.e. I want the dataframe columns that are outside the specified list.

I tried the following:
`quant_vair = X != true_binary_cols`

but get the output error of: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 545: given 155

Been battling for hours, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help:

```
df.drop(columns = ["col1", "col2"])
```

Comment: Of course! Silly mistake been staring at the screen for too long. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can either `drop` the columns from the dataframe, or create a list that does not contain all these columns:

```
df_filtered = df.drop(columns=true_binary_cols)
```

Or:

```
filtered_col = [col for col in df if col not in true_binary_cols]
df_filtered = df[filtered_col]
```